# Move to next Userform when MultiPage at last tab

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that directs a user to the next tab in a multiPage Userform. I need to add to the functionality that when the last tab has been reached, clicking the button will take the user to the next Userform instead.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim iNextPage As Long
With Me.MultiPage1
    iNextPage = .Value + 1
    If iNextPage < .Pages.Count Then
        .Pages(iNextPage).Visible = True
        .Value = iNextPage
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Any help gratefully received

Answer (score 0):

Multipages controls use the property Value to see the index of actual page. First page is 0, second one is 1 and so on

so if I type:

```
Debug.Print Me.MultiPage1.Value
```

I will get the active page from my multipage1 control.

also, you can set what page you want to see with value property. In Example, if you type:

```
Me.MultiPage1.Value=2
```

It will select page(2) of multipagecontrol (that means the third page, because first one is 0)

Also, there is another property. If you type:

```
Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count
```

You will get total pages of multipage control. Total pages is ALWAYS 1 more than the index of last page. Example: If you have a total of 3 pages, that means that the index (property value) of your last page is 2.

So your code should be something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_click()


If Me.MultiPage1.Value = MyForm.MultiPage1.Pages.Count - 1 Then
    'I'm on the last tab. Code to go to next userform
Else
    Me.MultiPage1.Value = Me.MultiPage1.Value + 1
End If

End Sub
```